# Maintain token when changing roles in Spring with OAuth2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using spring-security-oauth2 to allow users to use a token to access an API. However, I realized that changing the access roles of a given user with a generated token would not have any effect in it, meaning that if I want that token to have the new role, I need to re-generate it for the users. Is there any way to do it without re-generate the token for the user? Or at least a way to have temporarily 2 tokens for the same user and delete one after.

Thank you all,
João

Answer (score 0):

If your resource servers have access to a user database (or can call back to the auth server) then they can look up the account details (roles etc.) once they have validated the token. You would have to add an additional `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` or customize the `AuthenticationManager` that it uses.

Comment: I think, here we can use `RemoteTokenService` as it will do the same.

Comment: Maybe not. Doesn't `RemoteTokenService` just decode the token - you won't get more than that out of the box anyway?